# Style form elements in a div

Tags: css

I'm using Contact forms with Wordpress and I have the form in a div. The div ID is `contact_form_home`. I'm trying to style the form elements of the div with the following:

```
#contact_form_home input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea, input[type=submit] {
   background-color: #009fe3;
   border: 1px solid #fff;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 11px;
   line-height: 1;
   width: 100%;
}
```

For some reason any other textarea I have on my site also takes this style. How do I specify the styling only for that div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat the `#contact_form_home` for every element in the list.

```
#contact_form_home input[type=text], 
#contact_form_home input[type=email], 
#contact_form_home textarea, 
#contact_form_home input[type=submit] {
    ....
}
```

The comma `,` separates the elements completely, not only the sub-elements to the first id.

You should also see that every submit button every email input field has the style, but you probably do not have any other elements of that kind.

To make it more clear, your list reads like this:

```
( #contact_form_home input[type=text] ) 
OR ( input[type=email] ) 
OR ( textarea ) 
OR ( input[type=submit] )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to repeat the ID:

```
#contact_form_home input[type=text], #contact_form_home input[type=email], #contact_form_home textarea, #contact_form_home input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #009fe3;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 11px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```